# Showing tabbar at the top of screen in tabbarcontroller based project with scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, scroll, uitabbarcontroller

I have to implement a tab bar based application. There are two requirements

1. The tab bar item would be more than 10 and they should scroll not show in next page. I have got a reference of this and working on it. But i am not getting any starting point for this second one.
2. It should show(tabbar) at the top of the screen not bottom mostly like implemented in app as shown in the link http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/screenshots/21999/?lang=en.

So if any one has any idea or code then please let me know and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you cannot use UIKit's UITabBarController.

You need to define your own custom solution.

Possible solution:

1. put at the top of the screen a UIScrollBar
2. instantiate inside the scrollbar some UIButton of type custom and the image you define for each button
3. associate each UIButton to a different UIView (or a different UIViewController):
   e.g. Button1 --> View1; Button2 --> View2
4. each time you click on a button, just replace the view below the tab bar with the selected view.

In point [3] why it is better to use a view controller instead of a view? because using a view controller allows you to separate logic functionality for each of the tab bar functions, instead of cramming everything in the same view controller.
Basically you have one "main" view controller, which instantiates the scroll view (with buttons) and contains another subview (initially empty) called "container" that will take the remaining part of the screen. 
Now when you click on each button, you will alloc-init its corresponding view controller (let's call it "child1"), you will loads its view ("child1.view") and then you will add it as subview of the "container":

```
[containter addSubview:child1.view]
```

(don't forget to remove the existing subview in the container before).
Important note: the only view controller that will respond to events such as interface rotation will be only "main" and not "child". So interface orientation management must be still done by "main" and all orientation change events have to be sent by your code to the child container. 
The good of this approach is that the functionality of the single child can be fully implemented in its view controller and "main" will work just as a container and tab manager, with no core logic functionality.

It makes sense to move this logic to a higher level view controller for high reusability, but it would be quite more complex.

Comment: Thank for your nice explanation as explained in your [3] it's easy to implement view part but as logic is complex and data associated is also complex so i need to implement viewcontroller can you please guide me how to show/change view controllers on click of my buttons since the scroll view will also be on one of view controllers subview.please help me out.

Comment: see my edited answer; please mark as answered if the solution corresponds to your needs.

Comment: hi again thanks for your neat and clear explanation.But i am little bit confused about this line "It makes sense to move this logic to a higher level view controller for high reusability".And please let me know how to mark a question answered so that ican do it.

Comment: "Higher level view controller" consists in adopting the solution I explained before. With iOS5 this approach has been formalized with the concept of "container view controller" which intact declares a standard approach to build container view controllers as you want to do. But clearly if you want to use your app with iOS 4 then you cannot use that approach. To mark an answer as "answered" just click in the "white tick" marker on the left side of this answer.